# Right orgranization pipelines with docker images

Tags: dockerfile, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm trying to make optimization for the case:
I have a repository that contains a python app, configuration files for different environments for this app, and a Docker file for it. One Gitlab pipeline for building an image and many other per configuration files that use containers with this app. This pipelines are run manually. Each merge to dev or master branches GitLab pipeline runs linters/tests and build the docker for this app. After that new image pushed to the Docker registry. I want manual pipelines to have a particular container version. But when I merge my changes to the dev branch or merge the dev branch to master a new version of the docker image will be built. I think my architecture isn't good. I don't understand how to made it's better. I even don't know how to write requests on google or what to read. Can you give me any advice or give direction to read/search etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do such changes:

1. Build image only when requirements were updated.
2. Mount the script to the docker image in a pipeline.
3. Dev release - when I merge changes to the dev branch.
4. Release - when I merge changes to the master branch.